# WCF request-response logging via custom Trace Listener at one go

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, logging, log4net

At my WCF client application;

- I'm trying to log Request and Response messages into a single DB
  record. Hence, I need to match request and response messages.
- I want to use Trace Listener because it's an out of the box feature and want to log via log4net, however all I can recieve in a custom listener is the message string.
- The calls I'm making to the WCF service are async and in parallel.

Is there any way to match asynchronous requests and responses at Trace Listener level?

Comment: What do you mean by the "message string"?

Comment: The SOAP xml message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using **IClientMessageInspector** as I could not find a way to do it at Trace Listener level.

Using Ids in the headers to correlate the request to response.

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{            
        var key = request.Headers.MessageId.ToString();

        //Do stuff

        return null;
}
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{            
        var key = reply.Headers.RelatesTo.ToString();            

        //Do stuff
}
```